# load iframe on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i have a page with an iframe...
currently i used this code to load iframe on click..

here is my code

```
$('.a').click(function(){
    var iframe = $("#b");
    iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src")); 
});
```

html:

```
<button class='a'>Load</button>
<iframe id='b' src='' data-src='index.php'></iframe>
```

but i also i want to load iframe on scroll down (500px from top)

can someone please help me how i can do this...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(height  > 500) {
        var iframe = $("#b");
        iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src"));
    }
});
```

If you want to only load one time after scroll with more than 500 
you can add flag and set it to false on page load. Then set it true inside scrolling event and check for this flag before you load iframe

**Example:**

```
var isLoaded = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(height  > 500) {
        if(!isLoaded){
            var iframe = $("#b");
            iframe.attr("src", iframe.data("src"));
            isLoaded = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: i have update my answer please check it for more optimization

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to add a callback to the scroll event dispatched on the window object every time the user scrolls the page. This callback is used to load the iframe if it's not loaded yet and if the scroll value is higher than 500px.

```
(function () {
  var iframeLoaded = false;
  function loadIframeOnScroll() {
    if (window.scrollY >= 500 && !iframeLoaded) {
      loadIframe();
    }
  };

  function loadIframe() {
    if (!iframeLoaded) {
      var $iframe = $('#b');
      $iframe.attr('src', $iframe.data('src'));
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', loadIframeOnScroll);
      iframeLoaded = true; // could be placed in the onload callback of the iframe
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', loadIframeOnScroll);
  document.querySelector('.a').addEventListener('click', loadIframe);
})();
```